# How do I set the background color of the panel body in React Bootstrap?

Tags: react-bootstrap

In plain Bootstrap 3 I would do something like

```
<div class="panel">
   <div class="panel-body bg-info">
      Contents
   </div>
</div>
```

But in React Bootstrap we don't have a separate panel body.  Is there a way to set the background color?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set a custom style for the panel :

```
render() {
    return (
        var color = {
          backgroundColor: red,
        }

        <Panel header={header} eventKey={i} style={color}>
        </Panel>
    );
}
```

Comment: So, I guess you can't use the build-in css from Bootstrap, like "bg-info"?

Comment: I haven't tried but you may write " bsClass="bg-info" " instead of style={color}.

Comment: @CodeChimp Panel bsStyle (nor any of the currently available props) will modify the background color of the Panel.Body. (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#panels-props)